# Gnosis not working

Tags: gnosis

We recently needed to upgrade the gnosis infrastructure due to deprication of old version. Earlier we were using gnosispm docker images and now we have moved to safe global. Since the transition, gnosis has stopped working and we are not seeing any error logs to know exactly what could have gone wrong. Can you please help us out here. It is very urgent for us because due to this our whole production is down and users are unable to complete the transactions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.